# Getting WSAETIMEDOUT error in requests.get(url)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I want to fetch table data from a page and I am very new to this thing.
Code:

```
    import urllib
    import os
    import sys
    import requests
    import lxml.html as lh
    import pandas as pd

    url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm'
    page = requests.get(url)
```

Rest of code not used here as it is failing in this step.

I am getting following error in requests.get() statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 299, in recv_into
    raise SocketError(str(e))
OSError: (10060, 'WSAETIMEDOUT')
```

How can I fix this error ?
[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VtjEwMgG6vT4R08t2sz7YRh00CsrXOZw/view?usp=sharing) is the actual error because stackoverflow didn't allow to post full error.